# Can I mount /usr/src/linux from docker to my session?

Tags: docker

I need access to kernel sources from my session. 
Is it possible? 
Can I mount it to `/usr/src/linux/` ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible. It is documented in the [Managing Data in Containers](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) page. The syntax is to add `-v host_path:container_path` to your `docker run` command line.

For example:

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker run -t -i --rm  busybox
/ # ls /usr/
bin    lib    lib64  sbin   share
/ # exit
[root@localhost ~]# docker run -t -i --rm -v /usr/src:/usr/src busybox
/ # ls /usr/
bin    lib    lib64  sbin   share  src
/ # ls /usr/src
debug    kernels
```

Make sure the target mount point (here `/usr/src`) doesn't exist in your container already, otherwise you might have permission issues (not sure why, just experimenting with docker myself these days).